# Proximal Mapping of $L^1$ and $L^2$ norm

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, gradient-descent, proximal-operators

> We are given $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> We wish to compute the proximal map $$\arg\min_u \Big[\frac{1}{2\eta}||u-w||_2^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}u^Tu + \mu \sum|u_i|\Big]$$

I tried getting the derivative, but I ended up with something like $$\frac{1}{\eta}(u-w) + \lambda u + \mu \cdot\mathrm{sign}(u)$$
and I don't know how to deal with the $\mathrm{sign}$, so I can't isolate $u$. Am I going in the right direction here? Or is there another way to compute this?

Comment: In this case you generalized it even more. As they have different factors $ \lambda $ and $ \mu $.

Comment: You're trying to compute the proximal map of $l_1 + l_2$ norm. Luckily, for some functions the proximal operator can be computed as a composition (you can look for the formal justification). In this case $\text{prox}_{f+g} = \text{prox}_f \circ \text{prox}_g$, where $f(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{x}\|_2^2, g(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{x}\|_1$.